# Get all parents that don't have a child with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-selectors

I want to select all div's of parents using jQuery, that don't have children with the class `locked`

Example code:

```
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild locked'></div>
</div>
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild locked'></div>
</div>
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild'></div>
</div>
```

I feel like I'm really close:

```
$('div.myparent:not(:has(div[class=locked]))')
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use class selector, there is no need for attribute selector [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2115/)

```
$('.myparent:not(:has(div.locked))')
```

Note:- you can do like this too:- `$('.myparent:not(:has(.locked))')`

Answer (score 0):

1. child class and use not() to exclude locked class then use parent to locked on parent

```js
$(".mychild:not(.locked)").parent().css("color","red")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild locked'>1</div>
</div>
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild locked'>2</div>
</div>
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild'>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`jquery filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to `filter` out the `myparent` that does not have a `locked` child - see demo below:

```js
$('.myparent').filter(function(){
  return !$(this).find('.locked').length;
}).css('color','blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild locked'>one</div>
</div>
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild locked'>two</div>
</div>
<div class='myparent'>
    <div class='mychild'>three</div>
</div>
```